# How to use Unity3D Social for OSX?

Tags: unity, leaderboards, game-center, social

I can't seem to find any documentation using the Social APIs with OSX. I can successfully use the iOS Social Libraries, but when I translate it over to OSX, it doesn't do anything. Also please refrain from suggesting Prime31, as I know that option exists, but the functionality for OSX leaderboards/game center is natively built into Social API in Unity 4.1+ yet there is no documentation to be found!?

I want to know how to use `Social.ReportScore`, and the `ShowLeaderboard` UI Methods for OSX games. I would also like to know how to report achievement progress.

I've tried using the EXACT methods from the Unity.Social Library that works for my other iOS/iPhone/iPad games.  I've attempted the code in both C# and UnityScript (JScript) to no avail.

Please help.

Comment: What's your actual question? Do you want someone to provide documentation for everything? Is there a specific feature you want to use? Do you want to know how to best debug it not working? Are you looking for alternative libraries to use?

Comment: The libraries as of Unity 4.1 exist to support Leaderboard integration. However on Unity's Online Documentation it only entails iOS examples. Same with the user community's and most Q&A sites, only iOS examples. OSX is left in the dust.

Comment: I want to know how to use Social.ReportScore, and the ShowLeaderboard UI Methods for OSX games. I would also like to know how to report achievement progress.

Comment: OK thanks for updating that. Maybe you can also explain further what "it doesn't do anything" means and what you've tried to solve that. Could be you're already using it correctly, but it's having connection issues.

Comment: updated it, and it doesn't do anything means it doesn't throw any debugger information, doesn't alter the Game Center boards, and got rejected from the OSX submission process because Apple said the Game doesn't function as advertise in particular Game Center integration.

Comment: If your old code still works but new code doesn't, then at some level you *must* be calling a *different procedure*, or else you broke causality. Without some tangible demonstration of how the problem manifests (i.e. something that I could hypothetically use as a test-case to see if my solution works), you're still pretty much saying "it doesn't work".